# how to show two winforms at same time in csharp

Tags: c#, winforms

i develop a csharp application and i want to show the authentification form and the main form at the same time in the running of the application and also the main form should be disabled until i do the right authentification. i tried this code but it open two main forms one disabled and one enabled after the right authentification:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
    form2.Enabled = false;
}
```

and in the ok button of the authentification form i put this code:

```
Form1.ActiveForm.Hide();
Form form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question- Form2 will be disabled because you set it to be `Enabled = False;`

Comment: Your problem is that in your OK button routine you are creating a new Form2 object and showing it, where you should be referring to the original Form2 object you created in your constructor. You need to create a local variable to store the Form2 from the constructor and continue to refer to it in the other function. This will cause its own issues, but it's where you need to start from.

Comment: You might want to consider using more meaningful names than Form1 and Form2.  I assume Form2 is the authentication form, but it would be more obvious if it was named something like AuthForm.

Comment: form1 is the authentification form and form2 is main form

Answer (score 4):

Display a modal form. Please look at [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx) article.

```
// C#
private void ShowModalForm
{
   Form f = new Form();
   f.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Not sure if I follow what you're looking to do. But if authentication is successful, are you looking for this code in your click event? Put this is your `Ok` button event. By using `Hide` on your `Form1` you are still leaving the form open and therefor it will be modal and prevent use of `Form2`. Close `Form1` to regain access to `Form2`.

Based on what you are doing though your forms should be flipped. Your authentication form should be a child of your main form. In other words, open your form that requires access, then launch a modal form to initialize authorization.

```
// This should be on your initialization for the form that requires access.
public MainForm()
{
    AuthenticationForm f = new AuthenticationForm();
    f.ShowDialog();
}

// This should be on your form that grants access.
public AuthenticationForm ()
{

}

private void buttonOK_Click(sender object, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do your authentication here.
    // if successful then close this modal form to return to the MainForm.
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: sorry i haven't understand your code, it is like what i do isn't it??

Comment: I don't think your question is quite clear enough. A modal form will disable the parent form until closed. You could perform a `Boolean` operation to close the modal form once authenticated to close the form and make the other again accessible.